# Why hassle with requireJS, when caching performs so well?

Tags: requirejs

[image]

If you look at cached js files that get reloaded, you can see in the network panel that it literally takes NO time at all to reload them.

Why hassle with requireJS when you basically [can load 3 MB of js out of the main memory in less than 1 microsecond](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832)

Why bother?

Comment: would someone maybe recommend me how I can improve my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[looking at jquery parse times which typically take 10-100 ms, depending on the device](http://decadecity.net/blog/2014/04/03/jquery-parse-times) I would conclude that when there are actually many libraries, it is worth the hassle.
Probably in future, this need will degrade though (top end devices like iphone 5 have 10 ms parse time.)

Answer (score 0):

On one hand it's all about lazy loading of modules that isn't using frequently. On the other hand it's alway good practice to build amd modules in packages for production until http 2.0 will go in masses.

Comment: you have many libraries that you don't use frequently? I would argue, to only load the libraries on these rare pages. Instead of everything everywhere.

Comment: @Toskan everything depends on project. And on SPA you always have only one page. Or you loading everything at page start or later on demand

Comment: @Toskan and of course module patter is very good for developing loose coupling reusable components